# After filled, why my python turtle cannot draw any more

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am new to turtle and I am trying to draw two hearts with an arrow. But after I finished two hearts, it does not draw anymore. I already have the "pendown" and I don't know why it does not draw.

I have my codes here. Thank you for your help. ♡♡

```
# draw a big heart
turtle.pencolor('pink')
turtle.fillcolor('pink')
turtle.begin_fill()
turtle.left(90)
turtle.circle(100, 200)
turtle.left(20)
turtle.forward(285)
turtle.left(100)
turtle.forward(285)
turtle.left(20)
turtle.circle(100, 200)
turtle.end_fill()

turtle.penup()
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(150)
turtle.pendown

#draw a small heart
turtle.pencolor('red')
turtle.fillcolor('red')
turtle.begin_fill()
turtle.left(90)
turtle.circle(80, 200)
turtle.left(20)
turtle.forward(228)
turtle.left(100)
turtle.forward(228)
turtle.left(20)
turtle.circle(80, 200)
turtle.end_fill()

#draw an arrow
turtle.pencolor('black')
turtle.pensize(5)
turtle.penup()
turtle.right(80)
turtle.forward(400)
turtle.right(180)
turtle.pendown
turtle.forward(600)
```

Comment: Please share full code. Which library are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what turtle is but you write `turtle.penup()` but `turtle.pendown`. So this may be the problem

Comment: I can confirm this is the issue.  I have just reran the code with that fix.

Comment: Thank you! I was too careless for that. Thank you so much.